# jetbrains - intellij - automatically import projects on start

Tags: intellij-idea

I looked through the script that starts up intellij (on UNIX platforms) and cannot seem to find any arguments that would support automatically importing a project from the command line.

I'd like to simply kick it off from the command line, then come back with my projects fully loaded and ready to go.  Is that possible?

Comment: No, you can only specify a path to the existing project that will be open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a command line launcher by firing up IntellijIdea then :

1. go to `Tools`
2. click on `Create Command-line launcher`
3. specify a place where to save the launching script and its name
4. save
5. close Intellij

Open a terminal and navigate to the place where you saved the script and launch the command `./script_name path_to_project_to_open`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that, but I should specify, my project is maven and I want it to automatically import those projects.  I don't want to save my intellij / idea project files and directories.  I want those to be automatically generated.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand your needs, you want Intellij to open your maven projects when you fire up Intellij, right ?

Comment: Yes, if that is possible.

Comment: IntellijIdea can only open one project at a time, if you want to open a second project, it'd be another Intellij window. Maybe Eclipse would be of much use to you.

Comment: Right, I only want to open a single maven project at a time, but I dislike having to click through the dialog to import it every time.  My workspace is refreshed everyday, so the intellij configuration files / project files / etc. are gone.

Comment: The launcher is exactly what I need!